# Neutral word for half-hearted

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word that has the half-positive, half-negative denotation of *half-hearted* but none of the unenthusiastic connotations?

Comment: This might be a problematic request, since any thing that has half positive half negative will be well correlated with lack of enthusiasm.

Comment: You need to provide context and/or examples for this sort of request. Allow us to understand why "half-hearted" doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 3):

**Ambivalent:** simultaneous and contradictory attitudes or feelings (as attraction and repulsion) toward an object, person, or action (m-w.com)

Answer (score 2):

I think [neutral](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/neutral)  may suggest the half-positive and half-negative connotations of half-hearted without a negative bias:

> - of no distinctive quality, characteristics, or type.

- A half-hearted smile;  a neutral smile.

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[of two minds](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of-two-minds)*

> undecided; wavering: *he was in two minds about marriage*

*Collins*

I have only personally heard the *of* version. The *in* form has apparently diminished in usage in the later 20th century in the US according to ngram plots. In British English, the reverse seems true according to ngram.

See

> [*in two minds* - British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20two%20minds&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20two%20minds%3B%2Cc0)
>
> [*of two minds* - British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of%20two%20minds&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20two%20minds%3B%2Cc0)
>
> [*in two minds* - US](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20two%20minds&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20two%20minds%3B%2Cc0)
>
> [*of two minds* - US](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of%20two%20minds&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20two%20minds%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

A "muted" response? or "non-committal"

Answer (score 0):

**paradoxical:** self-contradictory
**bittersweet:** pleasure alloyed with pain
**lopsided:** inclined to one side

Answer (score 0):

**Reserved** - "There was no extra water, and their enthusiasm was somewhat reserved."

**Conservative** - "There are no guarantees - so we encourage conservative spending."

**Tame** - "They were surrounded by sleeping bears, so the applause for her speech was fairly tame."

Answer (score 0):

**Tepid**

> 1. (especially of a liquid) only slightly warm; lukewarm.
>    synonyms: lukewarm, warmish, slightly warm; at room temperature
>    "tepid water"
> 2. showing little enthusiasm.
>    "the applause was tepid"
>    synonyms: unenthusiastic, apathetic, muted, halfhearted, so-so, 'comme ci, comme ça', indifferent, subdued, cool, lukewarm, uninterested, unenthused
>    "a tepid response"

from Google's definition

Because tepid's primary meaning is a literal one related to water, it has very little positive or negative connotation because people generally don't have strong emotional commitments to water temperature.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that **indifferent** is a good word for this request.

[**Indifferent**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indifferent) via Webster's